# Creating UIScrollView Programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I am trying to create a UIScrollView programatically. I set a property and synthesize it.

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *topScrollView;
@synthesize topScrollView;
```

I then have a method that does this.

```
[topScrollView setFrame:CGRectMake(320, 0, 320, 65)];
[topScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(500, 100)];
[topScrollView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
[topScrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
[topScrollView setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:YES];
[topScrollView setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:NO];
[[self view] addSubview:topScrollView];
```

I put this in viewDidLoad.
This does not create the scroll view. I think it is because the scroll view has not been initialized. I can do the allocation and initialization in the above method but then when I want to use it in another method it wont work. I looked at [Programmatically added UIScrollView used in multiple methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10540936/programmatically-added-uiscrollview-used-in-multiple-methods?answertab=oldest#tab-top) but did not help too much. There is probably a simple solution that I am not aware of. What can I do to programmatically create this scroll view and be able to use it in another method(mainly to conduct animations with it).

Thanks,

Ivan

Comment: Side note - get rid of `IBOutlet`. That's only needed when using Interface Builder, not when creating it programmatically.

Comment: @rmaddy For completeness, it should be said that the `IBOutlet` won't hurt anything, and it leaves open the possibility that you *could* set the scroll view from a .xib or storyboard.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a UIScrollView Programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998336/how-to-create-a-uiscrollview-programmatically)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I think it is because the scroll view has not been initialized.

Right.

> I can do the allocation and initialization in the above method but then when I want to use it in another method it wont work.

It will if you assign your newly minted scroll view to a property or instance variable. That's what they're for.

Oh, one other thing. You'll need to make sure that your scroll view is retained somehow. That means changing your `topScrollView` property to `strong`, or adding it to a view (which will then retain it), or both.

Comment: Ok, so I created the instance variable:   UIScrollView* topScrollView;
and was able to get it to work. I later initialized it with         topScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc]init]; This worked. The other suggestion you made with the properties, what would I have to do there?

Answer (score 0):

Simple Method:
 You can created multiple times if you need means

```
- (void)scrollView
{

    int x = 0;
    int y = 10;
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        UIScrollView *scrollview=[[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, 50, 50)];
        scrollview.showsVerticalScrollIndicator=YES;
        scrollview.scrollEnabled=YES;
        scrollview.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
        scrollview.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        [self.view addSubview:scrollview];
        //scrollview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(50,50);
        x=x+55;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to add UIScrollView on yourView :-

Step 1:

```
Delegate "UIScrollViewDelegate" to your ViewController.h

for example:
  @interface yourViewController:UIViewController<UIScrollViewDelegate>
```

Step 2:

```
//create you UIScrollView
UIScrollView  *MyScrollVw= [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0 ,0 ,320 ,480)]; 
MyScrollVw.delegate= self;
[MyScrollVw setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
[MyScrollVw setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:YES];
MyScrollVw.scrollEnabled= YES;
MyScrollVw.userInteractionEnabled= YES;
[yourView addSubview:MyScrollVw];
MyScrollVw.contentSize= CGSizeMake(320 ,1500);//(width,height)
```

Step 3:

you want to implement the scrollView Delegates in ViewController.m

```
-(UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
   return imgView;
}
-(void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
   NSLog(@"Did end decelerating");
   //do your code here
}   
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
   NSLog(@"Did scroll");
   //do your code here
}
-(void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate{
    NSLog(@"Did end dragging");
   //do your code here
}
-(void)scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    NSLog(@"Did begin decelerating");
   //do your code here
}
-(void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
   NSLog(@"Did begin dragging");
   //do your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**The straightforward programmatically way in SWIFT**

To wrap it up

Create a `UIScrollView`

```
let scrollView = UIScrollView() 
scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

Use a Single Child View to Hold All of Your Content Subviews

```
let contentView = UIView()
contentView..translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

Usually, you only want your content to scroll in one direction. In most cases to scroll vertically. Therefore set the width of the content view to be the width of the scroll view.

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    contentView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.widthAnchor)
```

Attach four constraints (top, bottom, left, right) from our single content view to the scroll view.

```
    contentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor),
    contentView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor),
    contentView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor),
    contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor),
```

Make sure you have **constraints attached to all four sides of the content view** so that it will expand to the size of your content.

```
// After Adding your subviews to the contentView make sure you've those two constraints set:

    firstSubView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor),
    .
    .
    .
    lastSubView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor),
])
```

Reference: [Using UIScrollView with Auto Layout in iOS](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/03/05/uiscrollview-autolayout-ios/)